# How to add the two textbox value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This [link](https://jsfiddle.net/uevh54L7/) shows how I tried to add two text box values but the addition of the value is wrongly calculated.

This my javascript code:

```
$("#amount").on("input", function () 
{
    const originalDebit = $('#debit').val();
    const amount = $('#amount').val();
    const tot = parseFloat(originalDebit) + parseFloat(amount);
    $('#debit').val(tot);
});
```

Comment: hi tom its giving correct value, you enter 1 and the out put shall be 12346..

Comment: use three digit number

Comment: you got it man, check the solution given below it was happening because `amount` was becoming `NaN`.

Comment: Hi Tom! Still at it I see.

Comment: @ChrisG i posted it again

Comment: Why though? Do you still not understand why your code keeps adding to the debit value? Did you not understand why this works? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/zL4312a0/

Comment: yes i can't understand why it adding again and again.do you know ?

Comment: hey you using in span  i need in table format

Comment: Once you add to debit for the first time, you *overwrite* the original value from the database. At this point *it is lost*. There is no variable or place now where the original debit is stored. All you have is an increased value now. On the next keystroke, the current amount gets added to *the already increased value*, and this error keeps accumulating. I don't know how to explain this even simpler.

Comment: no what i have to do now

Comment: As for my code displaying the debit value in a span, here it is in a table instead: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/j0n5bwoe/

Comment: data-debit? is what

Comment: It's where you're supposed to output the debit value from codeigniter. The `data` attributes are a way to store additional information in HTML elements. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes With jQuery you can use `$(element).data("debit")` to read `data-debit`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n3y0rbjs/ see here it not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195732/discussion-between-tom-and-chris-g).

Comment: Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/q7oh5a2n/ (you removed the `data-debit` attribute, and used `.text()` to change an `<input>`'s value when you need `.val()`)

Comment: that i got that value using ajax

Comment: What? Ajax is used to load stuff from the server. Do you mean jQuery?

Comment: No i got debit value and credit value using ajax by changing the date in 3rd row

Comment: You can set `data` stuff using `$('#debit').data("debit", newValue);`

Comment: i cant understand

Comment: ....well, that's a problem. I've updated the fiddle with example code for your ajax success function: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/q7oh5a2n/ If you still cannot understand that, I cannot help you.

Comment: with same html code in previous fiddle use simple javascript code to add the value for two rows of column now you get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the value is a number or not with `isNaN()` OR empty before doing the addition. In such cases assign 0 to the variable.

Please Note: You also have to declare *originalDebit* outside of the event handler function to retain the original value on each change:

Try the following way:

```js
const originalDebit = $('#debit').val().trim();
$("#amount").on("input", function () {
  const amountVal = $('#amount').val().trim();
  const amount = (isNaN(amountVal) || amountVal == "") ? 0 : amountVal;
  const tot = parseFloat(originalDebit) + parseFloat(amount);
  $('#debit').val(tot);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="amount">
<p>D<input  value ="12345" id="debit"></p>
```

Comment: the value is not refreshing.if you clear the answer the old value is not displaying

Comment: @Tom, declare `originalDebit` outside the event handler function, updated the answer please check:)

Comment: you write but when i write you code in my coding page the result is not coming for me.

Comment: yes working i didn't say no.In js fiddle it is working

Comment: @Tom, then, I guess the issue could be somewhere else in your code in your actual environment!!!

Comment: i am working codeiginter.i don't know why the answer is not displaying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195730/discussion-between-tom-and-mamun).

Comment: i declare your answer is right but in my environment i didn't got answer

Comment: @Tom, as we only can help you based on the problem mentioned in the question posted here. We can do very little to help you about your local environment...

Comment: @Tom, necessarily it does not has to be me, there are others who are avilable and can help you in that. This is how actually SO works....

Comment: please you itself help for me i have already asked that question nobody answer and i deleted that one

Comment: I gave Tom working code in a fiddle because he was asking this question yesterday (since deleted). I had the original debit as `data-debit` in the HTML and showed how to access and use that for the calculation. 04FS and I explained multiple times why his code failed. Not only is he apparently still not getting it, he's lying about his question from yesterday (we didn't post answers but definitely did answer his question). He'll probably delete this one now. Edit: Found it: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/zL4312a0/

Comment: i have got that variable using ajax then how i change in data-debit

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help you. I used javascript vanilla.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  document.getElementById('amount').addEventListener('input', (e) => {

    let {
      value
    } = e.target;
    let debit = document.getElementById('debit').value;

    value = value == '' ? 0 : parseFloat(value);
    debit = debit == '' ? 0 : parseFloat(debit);

    document.getElementById('debit').value = value + debit

  })

})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="amount">
<input type="number" id="debit">
```

Comment: This code has the same error as OP's (it keeps adding to debit with every keystroke).

Comment: @ChrisG i posted same question now. i used  the variable outside  handler but for my environment the value is not take for calculation

Comment: in that case there is a problem of logic. what he try to do is not the right way

Comment: he could use the event focusout or a button to trigger the event.